# How to solve the error "const inet::MacHeaderBase’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]"

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using the following header structure:

```
class MacHeaderBase extends FieldsChunk
{
    MacAddress srcAdd;
    MacAddress destAdd;
    MacTypes type; 
    int morebit; 
      
}
```

To set the `morebit`, I wrote `hdr->setMorebit(1)` as follows:

```
    auto packet = currentTxFrame->dup();
    const auto& hdr = packet->peekAtFront<MacHeaderBase>(); 
    DestAddr = hdr->getDestAddr();
    hdr->setMorebit(1);
```

However, I am getting error:

> passing ‘const inet::MacHeaderBase’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
> hdr->setMorebit(1);

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `peetAtFront()` returns an **immutable** chunk so one cannot change it. Use `makeExclusivelyOwnedMutableChunk` to convert it to a mutable chunk this way:

```
auto packet = currentTxFrame->dup();
auto& hdr = makeExclusivelyOwnedMutableChunk(packet->peekAtFront<MacHeaderBase>()); 
DestAddr = hdr->getDestAddr();
hdr->setMorebit(1);
```

**EDIT**
`peekAtFront()` should be used when one want to *read* a chunk and its fields. The recommended way to *modify* a chunk of a packet is:

- use `removeAtFront()` to obtain a chunk and remove it from a packet
- modify that chunk
- insert that chunk to a packet using `insertAtFront()`

Comment: Jerzy, I tried with ```makeExclusivelyOwnedMutableChunk``` , but the problem is after setting the bit with above code at the sending end, when I am reading the same bit at the receiving end, it is appearing 0 all time. Would you suggest why it is not working and what is the solution?

Comment: The above error is appearing with the code given above (i.e. with peekAtFront).

Comment: With popAtFront that you suggested under "EDIT", I'm getting runtime error : "Implicit chunk serialization is disabled to prevent unpredictable performance degradation (you may consider changing the Chunk::enableImplicitChunkSerialization flag or passing the PF_ALLOW_SERIALIZATION flag to peek) -- in module (inet::physicallayer::RadioMedium) SensorNetworkShowcaseA.radioMedium (id=4), at t=0.17401257877s, event #121"

Comment: You are right. `removeAtFront()` should be used to change a chunk. I have edited my answer.